# PowerShell / XML - Copy xml file to folder according to node value

Tags: xml, powershell, file, copy, nodes

I'm fairly new to PowerShell but have used it in a limited capacity thus far.

So, here's my problem:
I have 100,000's of xml files which contain a node that has a State value.
I would like to use PowerShell to read the files then copy the files into their respective State folders. I can have the folders already created or have the PS script do it. Either would work but I would like to learn how to do both 1. copy the files to specific folders and 2. create the folders then copy the files to them.

Example:

XML1

```
<Member>
  <LastName>LASTNAME1</LastName>
  <FirstName>FIRSTNAME1</FirstName>
  <AddressParent>
    <Address>
      <Type>HOME1</Type>
      <Address1>123 STREET</Address1>
      <State>FL</State>
    </Address>
  </AddressParent>
</Member>
```

XML2

```
<Member>
  <LastName>LASTNAME2</LastName>
  <FirstName>FIRSTNAME2</FirstName>
  <AddressParent>
    <Address>
      <Type>HOME1</Type>
      <Address1>234 STREET</Address1>
      <State>NY</State>
    </Address>
  </AddressParent>
</Member>
```

To reiterate:
I would like to read the files that exist in a single folder.
Copy the files to their respective State folders according to the `<State>` node.

Also, there is more than 1 `<State>` node per XML file so I will need to use an absolute path (not sure if that's the correct term).

I want to thank you all in advance and any assistance you can provide is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Select-Xml` to extract the first `<State>` node in each document, then move the file based on that:

```bsh
Get-ChildItem |Select-Xml -XPath '//State[1]' |ForEach-Object {
  $State = $_.Node.InnerText

  # Check to see if folder already exists, otherwise create it
  if(-not(Test-Path $State)){
    $null = mkdir $State
  }

  # Move the source file to the state folder
  Move-Item -LiteralPath $_.Path -Destination $State
}
```

The XPath predicate means:

```
//           # Anywhere in the node tree
  State      # Find a <State> node
       [1]   # Select the one at position 1
```

Answer (score 2):

To start you off you can import each XML file using the [XML] type accelerator like so:

```
$GetXmlFolderPaths = (Get-ChildItem -Path "PathWhereAllXMLDataIs").FullName

foreach($XmlPath in $GetXmlFolderPaths){

    [XML]$CurrentXMLData = Get-Content $XmlPath
    $CurrentState = $CurrentXMLData.Member.AddressParent.Address.State 
    if($CurrentState -eq "FL"){
        <#
            Copy the data into the florida folder
        #>
    }elseif($CurrentState -eq "NY"){
        #Move to NY Folder
    }

    #etc etc.
}
```

Look up Copy-Item for synax on how to copy the XML files to their respective folders. Also feel free to use a switch statement above :)

You said there may be more than one State tag for each XML is that within the same node or a different node?